# Using Java Socket vs. Apache HttpClient for asynchronous real-time HTTP data gathering

Tags: java, android, apache, sockets

I had a quick conversation with a co-worker who asked if I knew how to use Java Socket for real-time data gathering in an Android app from an HTTP web server.  I am only familiar with using Apache's HttpClient, HttpPost, HttpResponse, classes.

What are the advantages of using the java.socket class vs. org.apache.http.client.HttpClient class for instantiating and running multiple HTTP Get requests for real-time data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I know and it may help you:

socket is just provide you two `Transport layer Protocol` `TCP/UDP`. `HTTP` is an `application layer protocol` on top of `TCP`. so if you want to communicate to an `HTTP` server you must talk to it with `HTTP` protocol. you can reinvent the wheel and implement the `HTTP` protocol using `java.socket` by yourself or use `HttpUrlConnection` or `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` or `OKHTTP`. All of them are using socket to access web server under the hood.

> What are the advantages of using the java.socket class vs.
>   org.apache.http.client.HttpClient class for instantiating and running
>   multiple HTTP Get requests for real-time data?

So in my opinion there is no advantage to use `java.socket` to communicate to an `HTTP server` unless you need a feature that dose not exist in any of those libraries.